# Access Cookies with particular name

Tags: javascript, html

```
function writeCookie()
            {
            document.cookie="employee=name,status,sal";
            document.cookie="dept = name,deptid";

            }
```

Here i set some cookies with "name= value"(Explicitly given)

If i want to access the cookies depending upon "employee" & "dept" then how can i proceed.
I did something like this `var x = document.cookie`. But it ll fetch all cookies.I want to filter depending upon the key(employee,dept) i set.Can some one tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function ? comes from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```
var getCookie = function (cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

You can find a full complete exemple here : http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username

**EDIT** : I added a function to get the whole cookie as an array `getCookieArray`. You can check the result in the console log.

```js
var getCookie = function (cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
}

 var getCookieArray = function (cookieString) {
        var subElements = cookieString.split(";");
        var subElemPairs = new Array();
        var subNameValues = new Array();

        for (i = 0; i < subElements.length; i++) {
            subElemPairs[i] = subElements[i].split("=");
        }

        for (i = 0; i < subElemPairs.length; i++) {
            subNameValues[subElemPairs[i][0]] = subElemPairs[i][1];
        }
        return subNameValues;
    }

document.cookie="employee=name,status,sal";
document.cookie="dept=name,deptid";

alert(getCookie("employee"));
alert(getCookie("dept"));

console.log(getCookieArray(document.cookie));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry for not understanding fully. But how can get all cookies relaed o "employee" & "dept" key.Could you please explain?

Comment: If you do  `document.cookie="employee=name,status,sal";` you can get the value with `getCookie("employee")` you will get "name,status,sal". I ll update my answer with a fiddle exemple.